# Can I use Linq syntax for join queries in sqlite-net-pcl?

Tags: c#, sqlite, linq

So I have a query

```
var query = "SELECT * " +
    " FROM OptionItem i" +
    " INNER JOIN Account_OptionList_OptionItem j" +
    " ON i.Id = j.Item_Id" +
    $" WHERE j.Account_Id={accountId}" +
    $" AND j.List_Id={listId}";

return _database.Query<OptionItem>(query);
```

I feel safer using linq syntax (so compiler tells me if I mucked up). But when I try this:

```
return from i in _database.Table<OptionItem>()
        join j in _database.Table<Account_OptionList_OptionItem>()
        on i.Id equals j.Item_Id
        where j.Account_Id == accountId
        && j.List_Id == listId
        select i;
```

or this:

```
return _database.Table<Account_OptionList_OptionItem>()
    .Where(x => x.Account_Id == accountId && x.List_Id == listId)
    .Join(_database.Table<OptionItem>().Where(x => x.Group_Id == listId),
        join => join.Item_Id,
        item => item.Id,
        (join, inner) => inner);
```

It takes a lot longer (I think it pulls the table into memory and then just uses System.Linq). Is there a way to use Linq syntax without getting a performance hit? (is there a library that supports this?)

EDIT: I'm using the nuget package:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

Comment: There are plenty of ORMs out there. The question is rather opinion based.

Comment: what exactly is your `_database` object?

Comment: ORM is sqlite. I use the nuget package sqlite-net-pcl.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

private readonly SQLiteConnection _database;

Comment: Your first sql query has a sql injection issue. It's important to use parameterised queries rather than string interpolation. Use a `?` in your string and add params to the query e.g. `_database.Query<OptionItem>(query, accountId, listId);`. Use DB Browser for SQLite (http://sqlitebrowser.org) to test your queries.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your ORM and Database, however in most cases the syntax is the same.
But it's not clear what do you wanna select and what is your model.
If you could provide your model I can help.